# PySNMP Produces Incorrect Results: Both NULL varBind Value and Timeout Simultaneously

Tags: python, pysnmp

I am using PySNMP to walk through a set of OIDs on a device with the following basic code (specific values taken out for confidentiality):

```
import base64
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

for (errorIndication,
     errorStatus,
     errorIndex,
     varBinds) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                     CommunityData(community, mpModel=1),
                     UdpTransportTarget((device_name, 161)),
                     ContextData(),
                     ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(walking_oid)),
                     lexicographicMode=False,
                     ignoreIncreasingOids=True):
    print(str(errorIndication))
    for varBind in varBinds:
        print(str(varBind))
```

What is throwing me for a loop is that this does work for many devices--but there are some devices where I get the following results:

```
No SNMP response received before timeout
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.<walking_oid> =
```

This indicates that there is both an error (SNMP timeout) and a varBinds value.  I'm not sure what the empty varBind value means, and I'm not sure why a varBind, albeit an empty one, would still print despite the presence of an error.  In addition, when querying this device manually for the same information, actual values are obtained.  Assuming that all of the input information (name, community, model, port, etc.) are correct, is there anything else that could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Once `errorIndication` evaluates to `True`, the rest of the return should be ignored. Why do you want to use `varBinds` in case of no-response?

Because of the way how `errorIndication` is returned (i.e. as a tuple), returning something for `varBinds` is also necessary.

It is frequently the case in SNMP that the number and the ordering of variable-bindings in request matches those in response (perhaps because in many cases `error-index` parameter is used to point to a troubling var-binds). Even in the case of timeout, request variable-bindings are placed into response just for consistency. That's why they do not carry any response value, just OIDs.

If the device is slow, may be increase response timeout in pysnmp? Otherwise enabling pysnmp debugging may reveal what's going on under the hood.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the errorIndication/Null value both being returned part.  As far as extending the timeout, when querying the SNMP manually from a remote server it comes up right away, and extending the timeout did not change anything.As for debugging, it gives =_BindValue: unspecified= after a large wall of text.  Then it says that "MP succeeded" but then immediately goes on to show "_expireRequest" and another large wall of text.

Comment: Do you see any response in the log at all? If so, sometimes pysnmp drops response if it come from an address which is different than the one pysnmp sent the request. This should be visible in debug...

Comment: How would I know whether or not there is a response?  I have to admit I don't understand the output of the debugger at all.  The wall of text contains a bunch of objects, but when it prints the response, _BindValue is always unspecified.  Also, by different address, do you mean that sometimes PySNMP can't always send a request from one server to find SNMP information from another server?  That seems to obviate much of the reason for PySNMP.

Comment: Consider using tcpdump/wireshark to observe the network for SNMP packets. Pay attention to addresses SNMP requests go to and responses come from - these should be the same. That's the thought I offered you to investigate.